# Scroll vim window in Tmux copy mode?

Tags: vim, tmux

Using tmux in copy mode, I cannot get the vim window to scroll. Is this possible? I'm trying to copy a huge chunk of text in vim inside of one tmux window and paste into another. Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest trying Tim Pope's tbone plugin instead: https://github.com/tpope/vim-tbone

Comment: https://github.com/sjl/vitality.vim

Answer (score 2):

I know what you ask for and I searched the net to find it as well. It is something that have bothered me as well. This however might help you with your problem:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4488 - a vim plugin. Not as fancy solution as to enter copy mode and scroll within vim instead of the history/scrollback buffer of tmux.

Comment: So there's no other way than installing/using a vim plugin on all the machine running accessed via tmux ? Wish the copy mode could do that, what a shame.

Answer (score 1):

try if this works for your needs:

```
function! SetTmuxBuffer() range
    execute "!tmux set-buffer '" .join(getline(a:firstline, a:lastline),"\015")."'"
endfunction

command! -range ToTmux <line1>, <line2> call SetTmuxBuffer()
```

put above codes in your vimrc or in a vim file and source it. then you can for example send line1-line8 to tmux buffer:

```
:1,8ToTmux
```

or visual select, then

```
:'<,'>ToTmux
```

go to another tmux window, try pasting the lines in vim.

Comment: Maybe use `system()` with `tmux load-buffer` so that you do not have to resort to `shellescape()` to properly handle all characters (e.g. single quotes): `call system('tmux load-buffer -', join(getline(a:firstling, a:last line), "\012"))`